# Count and group-by with Propel

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

In Doctrine I can do:

```
public function getCount() 
{        
        $q = $this->createQuery('q')
            ->select('*')
            ->addSelect('count(q.name) as count')
            ->groupBy('q.name')
            ->orderBy('count DESC');

        return $q->execute();        
}
```

How can I do the same in Propel in Symfony 1.4?

Answer (score 13):

Damned! It's easier than that!

If you need to count result rows for a given query, you need to use the `count()` termination method, basically:

```
MyTableQuery::create()->count();
```

Read the following documentation section for more information: http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html#query_termination_methods

If you want to add a `count` or `nb` extra column to your query which represent a SQL aggregate functions like `COUNT` or `SUM`, then you should use the `withColumn()` method:

```
$query = MyTableQuery::create()
    ->withColumn('COUNT(*)', 'Count')
    ->select(array('Name', 'Count'))
    ->groupByName()
    ->orderByCount()
    ;

$results = $query->find();
```

Comment: I think the OP was looking for something more complicated than just a basic count - something like `SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM x GROUP BY name` (the `SELECT *` in the question may be a red herring)

Comment: Be fair, and read the documentation. For your query, just write `MyTableQuery::create()->withColumn('COUNT(*)', 'Count')->select(array('Name', 'Count'))->groupByName()->find()`.
In both case, you're on the wrong path. Your down vote is not justified at all.

Comment: It's not my question, but nevertheless that's a much better answer! Would you edit your original response? (I politely disagree about justification, since your reply did not answer the question; however if you fix your answer I will happily revert the downvote).

Comment: I answered based on the title, I mis-read the code... Anyway, edited.

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
public function getCount() 
    $c = new Criteria();
    $c->addAsColumn('count', 'count(name)');
    $c->addDescendingOrderByColumn($c->getColumnForAs('count')); 
    $c->addGroupByColumn('name');
    return self::doCount($c);
}
```

There are some good snippets of info on propel queries here -> http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippets/tagged/criteria/order_by/date

Comment: You should avoid the use of criteria.

Comment: @WilliamDURAND care yo expand on that ? any particular reason ?

Comment: The ActiveQuery API is much better, really fluent, and it's the recommended API to use since 1.5. Propel2 will focus on the ActiveQuery approach, not on criteria/criterion. More hints on this blog post: http://propel.posterous.com/design-your-queries-like-a-boss

Answer (score 1):

Something *like* this:

```
$myRows = MyTableQuery::create()->
    addAsColumn('count', 'COUNT(name)')->
    addGroupByColumn('count')->
    addDescendingOrderByColumn('count')->
    find();
```

I'm not sure about the `GROUP BY` - you may need an alias, or to re-specify the `COUNT` clause. Try it and see what works by experimentation `:)`

You really **must** use an auto-completing IDE to take advantage of Propel (and Doctrine for that matter) - your queries will be much easier to construct.

My usual reply would normally be like @ManseUK's, i.e. based on the Criteria class - but that will be phased out when Propel 2 comes along, so it's probably a good idea to get your code ready now.

Comment: You don't need to write the query by yourself. Just think Propel provides termination methods like `find()`, and `count()` for instance. Propel aims to be as simple as possible ;)

Comment: As noted on your answer, a simple `count()` would be insufficient.